# How to install a driver for Canon MF236n?

Tags: printing, canon

How do I install a printer driver for my Canon MF236n? I downloaded the driver from Canon but I don't know what to do with it then.

Please let me know what commands I should use...

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to [UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100270810.html) and click to download and *save* what will be `linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken.tar.gz`.
2. Then *open* a terminal, *copy* one by one each command below, *paste* each command in turn into the terminal and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after each paste:

   ```
   cd Downloads
   tar -zxvf  linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken.tar.gz
   cd linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```

   and that final command will start the install script running. Watch it work; it may ask you some questions.

This driver was updated on the 9th Nov 2017, so we hope it works for Ubuntu 17.10.

**UPDATE:**

The latest driver for the MF236n printer can be found [Here](https://www.usa.canon.com/support/p/imageclass-mf236n) By Canon support.

Comment: This answer has unfortunately succumbed to link rot... Perhaps someone could test this replacement link: https://asia.canon/en/support/0100924010 which produces this filename: `linux-UFRII-drv-v580-m17n-04.tar.gz` I see this as 'supported': imageCLASS MF236n